# need to remove the array in json

Tags: node.js

var meds= [
    {
        "sno": 1,
        "brandName": "EPIDOSIN 8 MG INJECTION",
        "companyName": "TTK Healthcare Ltd",
        "price": "Rs. 17",
        "packagingOfProduct": "1 vial(s) (1 ML injection each)"
}
]

Comment: `meds = meds[0]`

Comment: need to remove the "price:Rs. 17 " to change the "price:17" need to remove the 'Rs. '

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment above you want 17 from Rs. 17 from your array.

```
var value =  meds["price"].split(""); // split Rs. 17 with space
var price = value[1]; // at index 1 you will get value 17
```

now you can do whatever you want to do with the price
if you want to set it back to the array, do this

```
meds["price"] = price;
```

Hope this will help!